Short sci-fi story about a Martian girl collecting specimens from Earth with her green pony
Plot Points:

The main character was a reverend/pastor/sexton or something similar, who was tending the church gardens when he was visited by a Martian girl and her green pony (it was hinted that the animal was not actually equine but looked like a Shetland pony with a green tint like algae)

The girl (think her name started with an A?) was searching for a particular kind of flower that grew in the reverend's garden. The reverend found out that she was collecting specimens to bring back to her planet before Earth was destroyed that day. The flower was the only specimen the Martians didn't have. (IIRC the reverend might've asked if they already had a human reverend?)

The girl tries to return to her planet, but her pony can't go back because it ate an Earth carrot (like Persephone and the pomegranate). The pony and the reverend wait for the end of the world together.


Other details:

Read in the 2000s in an American high school English lit textbook from the 80s, 90s or 00s.

The other short stories in the book were all by famous writers which makes me think this one was not written especially for the textbook.



https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1h0utyl/tomt_short_story_about_a_martian_girl_collecting/

That reddit answer appears to be an AI hallucination. I wouldn't bother mentioning it. No such story exists.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, you mentioned on Reddit that the girl's name began with the letter A. Is there anything else you can add?

@Valorum I hate that AI nonsense is starting to pollute all social networks. As if we didn't have enough with human spammers and trolls, now the AI is helping them produce garbage at an even faster rate. It's starting to ruin some of my hobby groups too :(

@AndresF. - Luckily it's quite easy to spot and remove

@Valorum I'm not optimistic. It already fools a lot of people (in that reddit link, the asker was semi-confused), and it will only get better. I've seen it used to fool people who were diorama builders with fake photos of dioramas.

@AndresF. - Like all spamming tools, the individual using it is trying to get engagement. By having very clear rules (you use AI, you get slapped) it'll discourage its use.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68264 doesn't particularly help.

@Valorum I also asked the question on reddit lol, I didn't realize the user was AI (I thought they were making stuff up but wasn't sure what the etiquette on calling them out was). The story ID checklist is helpful, but I can't think of any other details. It was only a few pages long

The girl can go back to Mars with her flower and other specimens, but the pony can't go back with his carrot?

@user14111 yeah I guess so? I'm pretty sure that's how the story went
